# JS disable event from fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am creating a vertical slider, where you have to scroll down 3 times (3 slides ), before seeing the content.

The problem is that once you've scrolled down through the 3 slides, the mouse scroll is disabled with this code (I think):

```
$(window).on({
  'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll
});
```

So I would like to find the way to enable the mouse scroll after the 3 slides. Any ideas?

[This is what I've done so far](https://codepen.io/palomatiessen/pen/eWqWVp)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if your scroll is tied to a full page scroller (like Fullpage.js) - but if it is, then this should work.

var count = 0;

```
$(window).on({
  'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll;
   count++;
});

if(count === 2){
   $(window).off({
     'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll
   });  
}
```